# editing and deleting records in a database using radio buttons

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
<?php

$user_name = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "my_db";
$server = "127.0.0.1";

$db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
$db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

if(isset ($_POST['name']))
{
$name = $_POST['name'];

if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO persons VALUES(' ' , '$name') "))

     echo "Successful Insertion!";

else

     echo "Please try again!";
}

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM persons");     

?>

<html>

<head>

    <style type = "text/css">

    li { list-style-type: none;  display: inline;   padding: 10px;  text-align: center;}

    </style>                    


</head>

    <body>

    <form action = " . "        method = "POST">

    Name:   <input type = "text"        name = "name"><br>
            <input type = "submit"  value = "Enter">

    </form>             

    <form name = "delete_form"   method = "POST"   action = "delete.php" >

        <input type = "submit"  name = "deleteRecord"   value = "Delete Record" />

        </form>

    <h1>List of Names</h1>

    <table border = "1"   width = "100%"   cellpadding = "5"   cellspacing = "2">

    <tr>
    <td><strong></strong></td>
    <td><strong>ID</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Company</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Edit</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Delete</strong></td>
    </tr>

    <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

    <tr>
    <td><input type="radio"   Name="id"   value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" ></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo "<a href = 'edit.php?id=$row[id]'>edit</a>" ?></td>
    <td><?php echo "<a href = 'delete.php?id=$row[id]'>delete</a>" ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>


    <form name = "edit_form"   method = "POST"   action = " edit.php?edit=  "<?php echo $row['id'] ?> >

    <input type = "submit"  name = "editRecord" value = "Edit Record" />

    </form> 


                </table>                

    <?php

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        echo "<li>$row[id]</li> . <li>$row[name]</li> <li> <a href = 'edit.php?edit=$row[id]'>edit</a> </li> <li> <a href = 'delete.php?del=$row[id]'>delete</a></li> <br>";
        ?>

    </body>

     </html>
```

---

```
    edit.php



  <?php

   $user_name = "root";
   $password = "";
   $database = "my_db";
   $server = "127.0.0.1";

    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $user_name, $password);
     $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

     $row = " ";

       if (isset($_POST['id']))
      {
     // if there is an id sent through POST and it isn't null/empty, use that
     $id = $_POST['id'];

     $SQL = "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE id = '$id' ";

     $result = mysql_query($SQL);

     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  }
  else
  {
    // otherwise use id sent through GET links
    $id = $_GET['id'];

   $SQL = "SELECT * FROM persons WHERE id = '$id' ";

   $result = mysql_query($SQL);

   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  }               

  if(isset($_POST['newName']))
   {
       $id = $_POST['id'];
       $newName = $_POST['newName'];
       $SQL = "UPDATE persons SET name = '$newName' WHERE id = '$id' ";
       $result = mysql_query($SQL) or die("Could not update database" . mysql_error());
          echo "<meta http-equiv = 'refresh' content = '0 ; url = index.php'>";
   }
 ?>


<form action = " edit.php"  method = "POST">

ID: <input type = "text"    name = "id" value = "<?php echo $row[0] ?>"<br><br>

Name:   <input type = "text"    name = "newName"   value = "<?php echo $row[1] ?>"<br><br>
       <input type = "submit"  value = "Update">

</form>
```

Hello,

The code above shows how to edit and delete records in a database. Originally, the edit and delete options were in the form of links to a php script which performed the required action. The ID number of the selected row gets passed to the edit or delete php file which then does the action that the user selects (refer to the comments in the code above) I am now trying to modify this code so that I can use a radio button to select a record and then edit or delete the record using radio buttons. I know this sounds trivial but I am having some difficulty with it. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Hello Tom. I have made the changes that you suggested but I it still giving the same problem. I have included the edit.php file in case you want to have a look.

Comment: "I am having some difficulty with it".Can you provide those ?

Answer (score 0):

The value of your radio buttons needs to contain the ID of the record to be edited.

```
<td><INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="radio" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"></td>
```

Then when you submit the form, you will know the record you are editing has id of value `$_POST['radio']`.

Though you are already using `GET` method to pass IDs (through your edit and delete links). I would recommend having consistency, and passing all IDs with parameter `id`. So

**Use this**

```
    <td><?php echo "<a href = 'edit.php?id=$row[id]'>edit</a>"; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo "<a href = 'delete.php?id=$row[id]'>delete</a>"; ?></td>
```

**And this**

```
<td><input type="radio" name="id" value="<?php echo $row[id]; ?>"></td>
```

Then in **edit.php** and **delete.php**, check to see if an ID was passed through `POST` (if someone submitted the form) or through `GET` (they clicked a link), then use whichever has a value.

```
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST['id']))
    {
        // if there is an id sent through POST and it isn't null/empty, use that
        $id = $_POST['id'];
    }
    else
    {
        // otherwise use id sent through GET
        $id = $_GET['id'];
    }
```

I should also mention that `mysql_fetch_array` is deprecated and you should be using PDO or MySQLi. Read more here: http://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array

Comment: Hello Tom. Thank you for your quick response. I have made the changes you suggested, however, I am still having the same problem. I have included the code I use for the 'edit.php' in case it might help.